# I want to push id and parent in a nested JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have nested JSON

```
[
{
    "heading": [
        {
            "name": "Heading 01",
            "Items": [
                {
                    "name": "Item 01",
                    "layers": [
                        {
                            "name": "layer01",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "layer02",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I am trying to push **id**, **parent** and **draggable** key value pair to nested JSON and output should be like this

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "parent": 0,
    "droppable":true,
    "heading": [
        {
            "name": "Heading 01",
            "id": 2,
            "parent": 1,
            "droppable":true,
            "Items": [
                {
                    "name": "Item 01",
                    "id": 3,
                    "parent": 2,
                    "droppable":true,
                    "layers": [
                        {
                            "name": "layer01",
                            "parent": 3,
                            "id":4,
                            "droppable":false
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "layer02",
                            "parent": 3,
                            "id":4,
                            "droppable":false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }]
```

But when I tried using `arr.forEach` I am not getting the expected output.

```js
let treedata = [
{
    "heading": [
        {
            "name": "Heading 01",
            "Items": [
                {
                    "name": "Item 01",
                    "layers": [
                        {
                            "name": "layer01",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "layer02",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
  function addUniqueID(arr) {
    arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
      obj.parent = JSON.parse (`${i}`);
      obj.id = JSON.parse(`${i}`);
      obj.text =`${i}`;
      if (obj.heading) {
        addUniqueID(obj.heading);
      }
      // if (obj.layers) {
      //   addUniqueID(obj.layers);
      // }
    });
  }
  addUniqueID(treedata);
  console.log(treedata);
```

Comment: What is the condition for droppable?

Comment: You appear to confuse JSON with object-/array literals. What you have in your question doesn't have anything to do with JSON. `JSON.parse (\`${i}\`)` doesn't make much sense. It effectively has the same result as just `i`.

Comment: @Nitheesh it’s should be true if nested array of objects in same level it should be false, thanks

Comment: I tried to convert to string to number that’s the reason I added but I am not able to push to nested array of objects @Ivar, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the id as parameter to the function and increase by one in each depth.

```js
let treedata = [
    {
        "heading": [
            {
                "name": "Heading 01",
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Item 01",
                        "layers": [
                            {
                                "name": "layer01",
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "layer02",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ];
    function addUniqueID(arr, i) {
      arr.forEach((obj) => {
        obj.parent = i;
        obj.id = i + 1;
        obj.text = i + "";
        obj.droppable = true;
        if (obj.heading) {
          addUniqueID(obj.heading, i+1);
        }
        else if (obj.layers) {
           addUniqueID(obj.layers, i+1);
        }
        else if (obj.Items) {
           addUniqueID(obj.Items, i+1);
        } else {
          obj.droppable = false;
        }
      });
    }
    addUniqueID(treedata, 0);
    console.log(treedata);
```

Comment: Thanks for the output is there any chance I can push  draggable true for nested JSOn and draggble as false for same level json

Comment: Please check edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Anoter one recursive solution

```js
const treedata = [{heading:[{name:"Heading 01",Items:[{name:"Item 01",layers:[{name:"layer01"},{name:"layer02"}]}]}]}];

const makeNextId = () => {
  let count = 0;
  return () => count += 1;
};
const nextId = makeNextId();

const iter = (data, parent = 0) => data.map((obj) => {
  const arrayKeys = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => Array.isArray(obj[key]));
  const droppable = Boolean(arrayKeys.length);
  const id = nextId();
  return { 
    ...obj, 
    id, 
    parent, 
    droppable, 
    ...Object.fromEntries(arrayKeys.map((key) => [key, iter(obj[key], id)] ))
  }
});

const result = iter(treedata);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use recursion and pass id as a parameter. Something like this:

```js
let treedata = [
{
    "heading": [
        {
            "name": "Heading 01",
            "Items": [
                {
                    "name": "Item 01",
                    "layers": [
                        {
                            "name": "layer01",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "layer02",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
  function addUniqueID(arr, id) {
    arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
      obj.parent = id - 1;
      obj.id = id;
      if (obj.heading) {
        addUniqueID(obj.heading, id + 1);
      }
      if (obj.Items) {
        addUniqueID(obj.Items, id + 1);
      }
      if (obj.layers) {
        addUniqueID(obj.layers, id + 1);
      }
    });
  }
  addUniqueID(treedata, 1);
  console.log(treedata);
```

Comment: Thanks for the output is there any chance I can add draggable true for nested JSOn and draggble as false for same level json

Comment: what do you mean by same level json

Answer (score 0):

How about this recursion? passing `parent` along the tree so that id would get proper value.

```js
var data = [{
  "heading": [{
    "name": "Heading 01",
    "Items": [{
      "name": "Item 01",
      "layers": [{
          "name": "layer01",
        },
        {
          "name": "layer02",
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]


const iterate = (obj, parent) => {
  if (!obj) {
    return;
  }
  parent = parent || 0;
  var my_id = parent

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    var value = obj[key]
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.parent = parent;
        value.id = ++my_id
        value.droppable = true;
      }
      iterate(value, my_id)
    }
  })
}
iterate(data);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```